# NoClassDefFoundError when class is in JBoss 6 WAR WEB-INF/classes folder

Tags: java, classpath, war, noclassdeffounderror, jboss6.x

My problem is that I have a web application built and deployed as a WAR file to JBoss 6.  My servlet fails to load a class in my app and throws a NoClassDefFoundError.

I confirmed that this class exists in the correct location of the WAR file.  All of my application classes exist in the WEB-INF/classes folder, along with my servlet class which executes without a hitch.  In fact, it seems it is just this one class that is not on the classpath because other aspects of the application run great.

JBoss is running on JDK 1.6_21, the app was built with JDK 1.6_24, this shouldn't be an issue right?

Further this app runs fine locally within Eclipse, and when I deploy the WAR file to a seperate Tomcat 7 and Glassfish 3 server they both find this class without a problem.

I am not expecting anybody to just instantly know whats wrong, if anybody has seen something like this happen before then please share your experiences, or if you have good tips or know of good tools for REALLY getting deep into classpath issues then please share.

Comment: What is the class it is complaining about?  More than likely, JBoss already provides this class in its system/shared jars and it is colliding with the class in your war.  I do not have a solution, only my sympathies as solving class loading and isolation issues with JBoss is not fun or easy.

Comment: It is my class.  JBoss wouldn't already have it packaged unless they snuck in my office and stole it while I was grabbing coffee :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class was "loaded" but the class definition could not be built. It usually happen when there is an exception in the static initialization of the class. 
I have seen more than once in AppServers that exceptions during the static initialization is not reported in the log file.

Check the static blocks and initialization of static attributes of the class that is failing for potential causes of exceptions.

Another cause that I have seen in JBoss and WebSphere is that the web application is distributing some library that conflicts with a library in the app server (like servlet.jar or something). Usually the problem is solved by removing the offending library or tweaking the classloading mechanism to "parent first".

hope this helps

Comment: You certainly gave me some things to think about.  Good tips!  I will investigate and let you know if this solves my problem.

Comment: Awesome!  You were right about checking the static initializers, there was a property file that was being referenced incorrectly and an NPE was being thrown.  I never would have thought that JBoss would deceptively not log exceptions that happen during static initialization of classes.

Comment: Thank you! I thought NoClassDefFoundError meant that the class was not loaded. This is an eye-opener.